# How to find a position from list coordinates data points

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

> I have list coordinates data points

```
{63.2802, 20.2614}, {61.5142, 24.8447}, {59.3288, 29.4583}, {56.9188, 33.6827}, {53.8731, 38.1929}, {51.5246, 41.1474}, {47.8597, 43.6472}, {47.6348, 40.8387}, {46.5147, 39.3611}, {45.7298, 37.748}
```

> If I have a known coordinate, e.g.

```
{47.8597, 43.6472}
```

> How to know the position of these known coordinate from the list?

Comment: Check [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html).

Answer (score 2):

As mention in the comment, you can use `Position[expr,pattern]` to locate,

```
list = {{63.2802, 20.2614}, {61.5142, 24.8447}, {59.3288, 29.4583}, {56.9188, 33.6827},
 {53.8731, 38.1929}, {51.5246, 41.1474}, {47.8597, 43.6472}, {47.6348, 40.8387}, {46.5147, 
       39.3611}, {45.7298, 37.748}};

Position[list, {47.8597, 43.6472}]
```

> {{7}}

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long list of coordinates and you're frequently having to find positions, a faster approach might be to use [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) to get an association between elements of a list and their positions:

```
coords = {{63.2802, 20.2614}, {61.5142, 24.8447}, {59.3288, 29.4583}, {56.9188, 33.6827}, {53.8731, 38.1929}, {51.5246, 41.1474}, {47.8597, 43.6472}, {47.6348, 40.8387}, {46.5147, 39.3611}, {45.7298, 37.748}};
indexassoc = PositionIndex[coords]

(* <|{63.2802, 20.2614} -> {1}, {61.5142, 24.8447} -> {2}, {59.3288, 29.4583} -> {3},  
     {56.9188, 33.6827} -> {4}, {53.8731, 38.1929} -> {5}, {51.5246, 41.1474} -> {6}, 
     {47.8597, 43.6472} -> {7}, {47.6348, 40.8387} -> {8}, {46.5147, 39.3611} -> {9}, 
     {45.7298, 37.748} -> {10}|> *)
```

Once you have that, you can easily find the position of any coordinate pair by, for example,

```
indexassoc[{47.8597, 43.6472}]
indexassoc[{61.5142, 24.8447}]

(* 
   {7}
   {2} 
*)
```

**Update:** `PositionIndex` works on 10.4 and above, but for 10.3 and lower you could build the association explicitly:

```
indexassoc = Association[#1 -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{#, Range@Length@#}]] &@coords;
indexassoc[{47.8597, 43.6472}]
indexassoc[{61.5142, 24.8447}]

(* 
   7
   2
*)
```

**Comparisons**

While you do have the overheads of constructing the `Association`, if you have to search more than a few times, it quickly becomes worth it. Trying out some different methods on longer lists:

```
list = Join[RandomReal[{0, 50}, {999999, 2}], {{47.8597, 43.6472}}];

AbsoluteTiming@Nearest[list -> "Index", {47.8597, 43.6472}]
AbsoluteTiming@Position[list, {47.8597, 43.6472}]

(* {0.00471799, {1000000}}
   {0.514604, {{1000000}}} *)

AbsoluteTiming[indexassoc = PositionIndex[list];]
AbsoluteTiming@indexassoc[{47.8597, 43.6472}]

(* {2.48619, Null}  -- It takes a while to build 
   {7.15318*10^-6, 1000000}  -- but is several orders of magnitude faster once you have it *)
```

Comment: I used Wolfram Mathematica 10.3, but It's not work in my computer. Do you have advice to me?. Because any output mesage: Missing["KeyAbsent", {47.8597, 43.6472}]

Comment: @SelfA See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{63.2802, 20.2614}, {61.5142, 24.8447}, {59.3288, 29.4583},                 
        {56.9188, 33.6827}, {53.8731, 38.1929}, {51.5246, 41.1474}, 
        {47.8597, 43.6472}, {47.6348, 40.8387}, {46.5147, 39.3611}, 
        {45.7298, 37.748}}

Nearest[list -> "Index", {47.8597, 43.6472}]

{7}
```

If you want to search for more indices:

```
Nearest[list -> "Index", {{47.8597, 43.6472}, {45.7298, 37.748}}]

{{7}, {10}}
```

Comment: I used Wolfram Mathematica 10.3, but It's not work in my computer. Do you have advice to me?

Comment: @SelfA For Mathematica 10.3, use `Nearest[list -> Range@Length@list, {47.8597, 43.6472}]`

Comment: @mrz It's work in my computer.